# how to bind datagrid to collectionviewsource using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid which is bound to a collectionviewsource, which is bound to an observablecollection.  In following a guide I've set it up like so:

My Persons class:

```
public class Persons : ObservableCollection<Person>
{
    //...
}
```

The xaml data bindings:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Persons x:Key="_Persons"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsPersons" Source="{StaticResource _Persons}" />                       
</Window.Resources>
```

The datagrid binding:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsPersons}}"/>
```

The code behind:

```
_Persons = (Persons)this.Resources["_Persons"];
_persons = //some method to fill perons;
cvsPersons = (CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["cvsPersons"];             
cvsPersons.Source = _Persons;
```

The above works.  **My question is, why do I need to set the collectionviewsource.source in code behind using cvsPersons.Source = _Persons;?  I thought the xaml in my very first snippet did this job:**

```
_cvsPersons.Source = _Persons;
```

If I need all this code behind then the xaml databinding code seems of little benefit, I may as well do everything in code behind.  From my (perhaps little) understanding, the only code needed in code behind would be to reference the instances setup by xaml, ie:

```
_Persons = (Persons)this.Resources["_Persons"];
_persons = //some method to fill perons;
cvsPersons = (CollectionViewSource)this.Resources["cvsPersons"];
```

If I don't have  _cvsPersons.Source = _Persons; then my datagrid does not get populated.  My xaml as it stands doesn't do the job.  I guess my question is more concept related..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To avoid your code behind approach you should use the MVVM-pattern [MVVM Model View ViewModel](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13347.mvvm-model-view-viewmodel-part-1.aspx) . A possible solution could be a "Person" (acting as the Model) like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The you could implement a ViewModel initializing a property with an ObservableCollection of Persons.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }
}
```

Your MainWindow.cs now has to initialize the ViewModel:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new ViewModel();

        ViewModel.Persons.Add(new Person
        {
            Age = 29,
            Name = "Mustermann"
        });

        ViewModel.Persons.Add(new Person
        {
            Age = 35,
            Name = "Meyer"
        });

        this.DataContext = ViewModel;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

It is important to set the DataContext to the ViewModel object. I added a Button an the method to add a Person.

```
    private void AddPersonOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Persons.Add(new Person
        {
            Age = 55,
            Name = "Sand"
        });
    }
```

Now you can instantiate an CollectionViewSource in XAML and bind it to the Persons ObservableCollection property in your ViewModel.

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridStackoverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PersonsCollectionViewSource" Source="{Binding Persons}" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PersonsCollectionViewSource}}" />
    <Button x:Name="AddPerson" Grid.Row="1" Click="AddPersonOnClick" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Add Person</Button>
</Grid>
```

Finally you have to set the ItemsSource as you posted it to the CollectionViewSource and it works like a charm.

**EDIT**

I tried your solution and it's working as well. MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <dataGridStackoverflow:Persons x:Key="Persons" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PersonsCollectionViewSource" Source="{StaticResource Persons}" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PersonsCollectionViewSource}}" />
    <Button x:Name="AddPerson" Grid.Row="1" Click="AddPersonOnClick" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Add Person</Button>
</Grid>
```

And it's important that you initialize your Persons Collection after the *InitializeComponent()*. MainWindow.cs

```
        InitializeComponent();
        Persons persons = (Persons)this.FindResource("Persons");

        persons.Add(new Person
        {
            Age = 23,
            Name = "Dude"
        });
```

This solution works without code-behind constructs to set the ItemsSource.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Got it working.  Cheers for the method on MVVM as well.