# Datagrid is not supported in a Windows Apps Project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to following along with this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227262/how-to-bind-datagrid-to-collectionviewsource-using-xaml), however I am Visual Studio is complaining about the Datagrid is not supported in a Windows Apps project? Is there an alternative to Datagrid that I could use?

Ultimately I would like to create a grid of buttons that correspond to a **MenuItem** that is in a **List menuLists**.

I am new to databinding, so if anyone has better things I should be looking at, please let me know.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.Pages.MenuItemsPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1.Pages"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MenuItemsCollectionViewSource" Source="{Binding MenuItems}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row ="0" ItemsSource ="{Binding Source = {StaticResource MenuItemsCollectionViewSource}}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem solved for me when I changed `Targer framework` to `.NET Framework 4.5`. Originally it was `NET Framework 3`. It can be changed in project properties.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I'm supposed to use GridView instead when I'm working on Pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no control. There may be third party controls, or you can get similar layouts by templating a ListView.